# What is the best way to increase my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, windows-7

I am now using Xubuntu in dual-boot with Windows7 and I need more space for Ubuntu. I had installed it for testing purposes because before 12.04 I had no support for this laptop, but now it works fine and I mainly use Xubuntu.

In the image below the Win7 partition is that from the right, the Ubuntu OS is on the small one in the middle. I think I should extend to the left, and before that, move files from the large partition (that has no OS on it) onto the Win7 partition, and then extend the Ubuntu partition into the free space created on the big one.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have this worked out perfectly already:

1. move some files from sda2 to sda3 to free up some space,
2. shrink sda2,
3. move and extend sda4 to the left, because it holds sda5 and needs to be extended first,
4. move and extend sda5 to the left.

“[Moving Space Between Partitions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions)” basically performs steps 2–4 in reverse, if you want a more detailed and credible source.

**Warning: back up the data on sda2 and sda5 if you value it!** Shrinking and moving around file systems is relatively risky and can leave them corrupted and their data inaccessible.

Comment: what is the 'move' action and in what is it different from resizing? other problem is that sda 4 and 5 have to be resized from a live cd boot. i tried already to do all these actions from a live gparted usb stick, but because of the poor suport fot my gpu card the gpu got so hot that the pc shut down. luckily all was ok and i shrunk the big partition after booting in xubuntu. i have to use a live 14.04 live usb to carry on

Comment: Moving, shrinking, and extending – while technically separate operations – are all gathered in the operation called “Resize/Move” in GParted. And yes you need to do that from a live system, because you cannot modify mounted partitions. If you have trouble with the graphics driver, Ubuntu provides a fallback graphics mode for the live system in its boot menu.

Comment: the gpu problem is not present in 14.04. i will either use that live cd which comes with a kernel that is now adapted to my gpu, or use a resizing tool in windows like [this one](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)

Comment: You can use an Ubuntu 14.04 live system to manage your partitions. The Windows-based partition manager may work too except for the growth of sda5, which can be done online in Ubuntu. Please search or open another question for that along the lines “How do I grow my ext4 partition online?“

Comment: i have moved the ubuntu partition using the tool from win7 and now the unallocated space is at the right of it, and indeed i cannot extend it with the same tool. i will create a live usb with the xubuntu 14.04 tested for gpu support and boot that. - but what  do you mean by doind that "online"?

Comment: Ext4 file systems (and many others) can be grown while they're mounted (see [`resize2fs(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/resize2fs.8.html)). So you don't necessarily need to use a live system, but it will probably be easier.